# Spring import application context from another project

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, transactions, annotations

I have 2 projects, one of them is included in the other one build path, both of them have his own application context defining his beans.

I want to manage Global Transactions so I have to have in one application context the import of both of them, but I didn't find the way to do that.

It is possible have 2 application context in different project and import one of them to the other.

If there is no possible which would be the best solution?

I have think in become the 2 projects in 1.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes it is possible to import; in one of your appcontext xmls:

```xml
<beans>

    <import 
        resource="classpath*:/META-INF/whatever/root/to/otherAppContext.xml" />

    <bean id="beanA" class="..."/>
    <bean id="beanB" class="..."/>

</beans>
```

Comment: But my application its not a web application, I am going to give it a chance

Comment: That doesn't matter, if project A has project B on its classpath, then the project B appcontext is on the classpath as well, on a specific path. Use that in the <import>. (the ../whatever/root/to is a placeholder of course)

Comment: Thanks, I was a little bit clueless

Comment: Just what I was looking for.

Comment: And if I use only annotated classes instead of xml-ul for configuration how can I do this?

Answer (score 6):

This oldish Spring blog post describes pretty much exactly what you're trying to do.

http://blog.springsource.com/2007/06/11/using-a-shared-parent-application-context-in-a-multi-war-spring-application/

Comment: But my application its not a web application, I am going to give it a chance