# Test Spring Configuration File

Tags: spring, maven, testing

I have a spring configuration file with some beans defined in it, now I would like to use these beans in my unite/integration tests. Is there a way to do this without having a copy of the file in both the main resources and the test resources?

Comment: As 'main' resources are present in the 'test' classpath, you can just use the Spring import feature like described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468195/spring-import-application-context-from-another-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test class has to look like the following one:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:path/to/your/context.xml" })
public class MyTest {
  @Autowired
  private MyBean beanUnderTest;
}
```